# FluentValidator for Collection Item

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, fluentvalidation

I'm developing a C# .NET Core API. Using **FluentValidation** to validate a **DepartmentSelected** collection, and because this is a collection, I'm trying to use **RuleForEach**.

Given a Student and Department, I want to ensure that for every student  both English and Maths is a mandatory and must be included with other departments. But, if the collection is without English it needs to return a  validator message **"Please select English"**. If the collection is without Maths we need to return a validator message "**Please select Maths**".

The collection is allowed to have others departments. Here's the code

**Request Api**

```
{   "StudentId" : 3,
    "StudentName":"BNeena", 
    "StudentType":"Hostler",    
    "DepartmentSelected":
    [
        {"StudentId" : 3, "DepartmentId" : 1,"DepartmentCode":Language},
        {"StudentId" : 3, "DepartmentId" : 5," DepartmentCode":Maths},
        {"StudentId" : 3, "DepartmentId" : 7," DepartmentCode":Mechanical},
        {"StudentId" : 3, "DepartmentId" : 23," DepartmentCode":Aeronautical},      
    ]
}
```

**Entity Class**

```
public class StudentDetails()
{ 
   public long StudentId { get; set; }
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
   public string StudentType { get; set; }
   public List<Department> SelectedDepartment{ get; set; }
}    

public class Department()
{      
   public long StudentId { get; set; }
   public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
   public string DepartmentCode{ get; set; }         
}
```

**Fluent Validator**

```
 RuleForEach(t => t.SelectedDepartment)
    .SetValidator(new SelectedDepartmentValidator()); 

public SelectedDepartmentValidator()
{
           
    RuleFor(x => x.DepartmentID)
        .Must(x => !DeptList.Contains(x)) 
        .WithMessage("Please Select English");  
 }
```

**Code I've tried that does not work**

1. `.Must(x => x != DeptList.English)`
2. `.Must(x => !DeptList.Contains(x))`

I spent lot of time to figure it out, but seems nothing is helping. The problem I am facing here is  **RuleForEach** validates all the items in **DepartmentSelected**  collection and says "Please select English","Please select Maths" when it iterates for other departments(Mechanical, Aeronautical.

**Accepted output**

The validator needs to return "Please select English" or "Please select Maths" only if the respective (English or Maths) items are not in the **DepartmentSelected** collection.

Comment: Currently you are checking the SelectedDepartment list to see if every item in that list is either English or Maths, which it is not.  You instead need to check on the Student level to see if it has in SelectedDepartment  at least 2 items, and least one 1 is English and at least 1 item is Maths.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith no , The selectedDepartment is the collection which holds all student level with department level, Do check my DepartmentSelected  in Request Api part.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith i checked again, i am using DepartmentSelected  only.

Answer (score 0):

RuleForEach is needed if you want to check each element separately independently of other elements. for example the length of the name, etc.

In your case, you need to apply the rule to the entire collection. You were on the right track, you needed a ".must", only in the context of a collection.

Example:

In main validator you need one of this rule:

1. One common message if not containt any item from DeptList

   ```
       RuleFor(x => x.SelectedDepartment)
           .Must(selectedDepartment => DeptList.All(x => selectedDepartment.Contains(x)))
           .WithMessage("Common message.");
   ```
2. Message for each Dept

   ```
       RuleFor(x => x.SelectedDepartment)
           .Must(selectedDepartment => selectedDepartment.Contains(englishDepId))
           .WithMessage("Please select English.")
           .Must(selectedDepartment => selectedDepartment.Contains(mathsDepId))
           .WithMessage("Please select Maths.");
   ```